# Beam Python Dataflow Runner Uses deprecated BigQuerySink instead of WriteToBigQuery in apply_WriteToBigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In terms of implementation details within the DataflowRunner, a lot of people may not care about whether `BigQuerySink` or `WriteToBigQuery` is used.

However, in my case I am trying to deploy my code to dataflow templates with RunTimeValueProvider's for the arguments. This behavior is supported in `WriteToBigQuery`:

```
class WriteToBigQuery(PTransform):
....

 table (str, callable, ValueProvider): The ID of the table, or a callable
         that returns it. The ID must contain only letters ``a-z``, ``A-Z``,
         numbers ``0-9``, or underscores ``_``. If dataset argument is
         :data:`None` then the table argument must contain the entire table
         reference specified as: ``'DATASET.TABLE'``
         or ``'PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE'``. If it's a callable, it must receive one
         argument representing an element to be written to BigQuery, and return
         a TableReference, or a string table name as specified above.
         Multiple destinations are only supported on Batch pipelines at the
         moment.
```

It is **not** supported in BigQuerySink:

```
class BigQuerySink(dataflow_io.NativeSink):
      table (str): The ID of the table. The ID must contain only letters
        ``a-z``, ``A-Z``, numbers ``0-9``, or underscores ``_``. If
        **dataset** argument is :data:`None` then the table argument must
        contain the entire table reference specified as: ``'DATASET.TABLE'`` or
        ``'PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE'``.
```

What's even more fun is that `BigQuerySink` in the code has been deprecated since 2.11.0.

```
@deprecated(since='2.11.0', current="WriteToBigQuery")
```

However in DataFlowRunner, the current code and comments seem completely out of line with the expectation that `WriteToBigQuery` is the default class to use over `BigQuerySink`:

```
  def apply_WriteToBigQuery(self, transform, pcoll, options):
    # Make sure this is the WriteToBigQuery class that we expected, and that
    # users did not specifically request the new BQ sink by passing experiment
    # flag.

    # TODO(BEAM-6928): Remove this function for release 2.14.0.
    experiments = options.view_as(DebugOptions).experiments or []
    if (not isinstance(transform, beam.io.WriteToBigQuery)
        or 'use_beam_bq_sink' in experiments):
      return self.apply_PTransform(transform, pcoll, options)
    if transform.schema == beam.io.gcp.bigquery.SCHEMA_AUTODETECT:
      raise RuntimeError(
          'Schema auto-detection is not supported on the native sink')
    standard_options = options.view_as(StandardOptions)
    if standard_options.streaming:
      if (transform.write_disposition ==
          beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE):
        raise RuntimeError('Can not use write truncation mode in streaming')
      return self.apply_PTransform(transform, pcoll, options)
    else:
      from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json
      schema = None
      if transform.schema:
        schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(json.dumps(transform.schema))
      return pcoll  | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
          beam.io.BigQuerySink(
              transform.table_reference.tableId,
              transform.table_reference.datasetId,
              transform.table_reference.projectId,
              schema,
              transform.create_disposition,
              transform.write_disposition,
              kms_key=transform.kms_key))
```

My questions are twofold:

1. Why the difference in contract/expectations between the `DataflowRunner` and the `io.BigQuery` class?
2. Without waiting for a bug fix, does anyone have suggestions on how to *force* the `DataflowRunner` to use `WriteToBigQuery` over `BigQuerySink`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WriteToBigQuery` transform has two different strategies to write to BigQuery:

- Streaming inserts into a BigQuery endpoint
- File Load jobs triggered periodically (or once for batch pipelines)

For the Python SDK, we initially only had support for Streaming inserts, and we had a runner-native implementation for File Loads that only worked on Dataflow (this is the `BigQuerySink`).

For Batch pipelines running on Dataflow, `BigQuerySink` is replaced in - as you properly found. For all other cases, streaming inserts were used.

In a recent version of Beam, we added support for File Loads natively in the SDK - the implementation for this is in [`BigQueryBatchFileLoads`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.15.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_file_loads.py#L486).

Because we didn't want to break users relying on the old behavior, we masked `BigQueryBatchFileLoads` behind an experiment flag. (the flag is `use_beam_bq_sink`).

So:

- In a future version, we will automatically use `BigQueryBatchFileLoads`, but for now, you have two options to have access to it:

  1. Use it directly in your pipeline (e.g. `input | BigQueryBatchFileLoads(...)`).
  2. Pass the option `--experiments use_beam_bq_sink`, while using `WriteToBigQuery`.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your answer helped me understand the intent in the code I was reading. Out of curiosity - is more effective to message the ApacheBeam team on twitter or does your team pretty actively monitor stackoverflow?

Comment: Twitter is not a great place to get quick responses. We mostly use it as an announcement platform, and don't converse on it much. We look at StackOverflow, and we look at the mailing lists user@beam.apache.org, as well as the ASF Slack. See: https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/